# Fetch LinkedIn Profile Data using LinkedIn API without having to authenticate

Tags: linkedin-api

We are attempting to retrieve information such as the LinkedIn user's education, work history, experience, and other information. In our system, we only have the basic profile URLs of those LinkedIn users. Will we be able to view their profile and retrieve their profile information if we only have the Basic profile URL and do not require users to authenticate to our LinkedIn app?